# How to make a batch file that will run multiple queries in cmd and log them

Tags: file, batch-file, command, command-prompt, office-2013

I want to create a batch file that I can keep on a flash drive and take around to my users's machine's to determine their computer name and their Office 2013 License, I would then like the results to be pasted into a text file on the flash drive.

I know `cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus` works to get the last 5 digits of the product key but I do not know how to create the batch file to query the computer name, nor how to have it paste this information into a text file. Is this even possible?

Comment: No need to re-invent the wheel. [Produkey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) can do that for you. It's scriptable too.

Comment: Produkey is not exactly what I am looking for, it does not state that it saves the information, nor that it works with 2013. Plus I would like to learn how to do this myself so I can modify and resave the batch file to work for other applications too. Thank you for the resource though :)

Comment: I don't have any boxes with 13 on them to test with. Try it out and see if it works.

Comment: is anyone aware of a batch file could do all of this?

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this question, or a pointer in the right direction, not finding much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your text file is DataCollected.csv and assuming it resides adjacent to the batch file, some clues [untested]:

```
findstr /r "^%ComputerName%," "%~dp0DataCollected.csv" || for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus') do echo %computername%,%%a>> "%~dp0DataCollected.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow you hit the nail right on the head Parag! thanks

Now to make it even more complicated, is there a way to null out the write feature if there is no office 2013 license, and instead have it look for 2010 should it fail to find 2013?

Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Input Error: Can not find script file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VBS".

is what it returns on machines without it. if not, I can just edit that out in my DataCollected.

EDIT: This does print out the data, but it overwrites each time I rerun the batch file, almost there :)

Comment: If that answer helped address your problem, you need to use the mark as answer feature on stackoverflow. Next, you are now being greedy :-). Please see if you can edit the question and update it with newer requirements. I believe it should be doable based on the presence/absence of the vbs file.